# Insert into Select From Where (Selecting Last Same Row Data to Insert into the Same Table)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert rows using the same last values of rows in the column name bill period.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBfet.png]

this is my desired result, and after the billperiod 3 it goes into 4 taking the data rows of billperiod 3.

I tried other solution where I used the other table to use it as a where but this are the results.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJM19.png]

but It didn't work, here is the image of my other table

[image]

Comment: This is the image of my other table http://i.stack.imgur.com/UwqTX.png

Comment: **Pro tip: Images are hard to parse and recreate.** You force people who want to help to retype entire query. For better human support prepare **http://sqlfiddle.com**